# Which template or include file in Omega subtheme takes hook_form_alter()?

Tags: theming, forms

I want to use hook_form_alter in my Omega subtheme. I'm trying to put the function in the correct place but I'm getting no results after clearing caches and refreshing.

Here's the code:

```
<?php function rescue_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
  dsm($form_id);        // HTML5 placeholder attribute
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('enter search terms');
  }
}
```

I don't know whether to include a closing `?>` or not. I've tried it both ways. I've tried saving it as preprocess-page.inc and process-html.inc but neither has given any result. Help?

Comment: Have you tried putting it straight into template.php?

Comment: No, because there's a README in there that says not to do that, and instead to put it in a process or preprocess include.

Comment: Update: tried it for debugging purposes. It works that way. I'd still like to figure out the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocess.inc and process.inc files are an Alpha/Omega way of organizing [`template_preprocess`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7) and [`template_process`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_process/7) functions.  Basically, if your template.php would have a `mytheme_preprocess_node`, you would put it in preprocess-node.inc and name the function `mytheme_alpha_preprocess_node`.  When you clear cache, and Drupal rebuilds the registry, the Alpha hooks will scan all of these files and wire everything up.

This doesn't mean that everything else that you put in template.php goes in these includes.  Your custom theme functions and alters should still stay in template.php.

This can help keep the size of template.php managable, but I always still end up with large files because typically needs lots of theme and alter functions for the projects I work on.